# Where can I find the API key for my Google APIs in the Google Developer Console?

Tags: api, google-maps

I need to use the Google Maps Javascript API and the Google Maps Geocoding API for my project.

I created a new project and got an API Key.

The API key works with Google Maps Javascript API but not with Geocoding.

Do I need another key for this?

Thanks

Comment: It should be the same key are you running it in json or XML for the geocoding?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a [help document that answers this question](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys):

> ### Acquiring API keys
>
> 1. Open the [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential)
> 2. Click **Add credentials > API key** and select the appropriate key type:
>
> #### Server keys
>
> Create and use a server key if your application runs on a server. Do not use this key outside of your server code. For example, do not embed it in a web page. To prevent quota theft, restrict your key so that requests are only allowed from your servers' source IP addresses.
>
> #### Browser keys
>
> Create and use a browser key if your application runs on a client, such as a web browser. To prevent your key from being used on unauthorized sites, only allow referrals from domains you administer.
>
> #### iOS keys
>
> Create and use an iOS key if your application runs on iOS devices. Google verifies that each request originates from an iOS application that matches one of the bundle identifiers you specify. An app's .plist file contains its bundle identifier. Example: com.example.MyApp
>
> #### Android keys
>
> Create and use an Android key if your application runs on Android devices. To do so, you need to specify the SHA1 fingerprints and package names of the application using that key.